# HLS with FFmpeg, browser skips m3u8 in sequence

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm writing a program with C++, receiving 2-second-long mp4 video and converting it to m3u8 and same-duration ts files in real-time.

Problem is when I check it with browsers on PC, it doesn't load m3u8 properly.

For example, when I start to watch m3u8, it loads first m3u8 with #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE: 1, then it keeps loading first m3u8, then suddenly skips to #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE: 4 or larger.

Streaming still works, but it is very unstable due to that problem. It loads some ts together, then loads nothing while loading same m3u8 it already loaded, and skips 3 or more m3u8 and loads ts files together and again.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel level+warning -i SOURCE.mp4 -an -filter:v fps=fps=10 -f hls -hls_list_size 7 -strftime 1 -hls_segment_filename '1.ts' -hls_flags append_list+omit_endlist DEST.m3u8
```

This is ffmpeg command in my program, using hls_segment_filename option to overwrite ts files so I limit number of files under 100, and it runs every 2 second.

Maybe, I'm overwriting it too fast to be loaded?

Comment: You can’t convert segments like this. Ffmpeg will reset timestamps and continuity counters each segment, and it will confuse the player.

Comment: @szatmary Any advice? I can't change the environment receiving new videos and converting it.

Comment: You need to feed ffmpeg (or another tool) a constant stream of media coming in from the source. Discrete segment transcoding is VERY difficult, at [mux](http://mux.com) I have to write a custom program to replace ffmpeg to ensure proper timestamps, (especially b frames), counters, and handle audio priming samples to achieve discrete transcoding.

Comment: Always add `-re` when reading from files and writing to streams.

Comment: @szatmary Does the same issue apply here? https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/34627/audio-discontinuities-when-generating-hls-segments-in-different-processes Any idea for off the shelf tools that could help correct the timestamps (if that is the issue)?